Can the mean of a sequence converge without the variance of the sequence converging?
Is it possible to  have some sequence of random variables $X = {x_1, x_2, ... x_n}$ such that the mean of this sequence converges but the variance of this sequence does not?
I tried to think of an example where this is possible.
For example, suppose I define:
$$X_n = \begin{cases} 
n^2 & \text{with probability } \frac{1}{n^2} \\
0 & \text{with probability } 1-\frac{1}{n^2}
\end{cases}$$
I can calculate the expected value (i.e. the mean):
$$E(X_n) = n^2 \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} + 0 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{n^2}) = 1$$
Now, for the variance:
$$Var(X_n) = E(X_n^2) - [E(X_n)]^2$$
For $E(X_n^2)$:
$$E(X_n^2) = (n^2)^2 \cdot \frac{1}{n^2} + 0^2 \cdot (1-\frac{1}{n^2})$$
$$= n^4 \cdot \frac{1}{n^2}$$
$$= n^2$$
For the total variance:
$$Var(X_n) = n^2 - [1]^2$$
$$= n^2 - 1$$
Thus, it seems to me that as $n$ grows larger, the variance will grow without bound, even though the expectation remains constant at 1?

My simulation attempt to confirm this (if I did it correctly):


Simpler:  Just let $x_k$ be the uniform distribution on $[-k, k]$.  The mean is always $0$, but the variance grows like $k^2$.

Also simpler: let $Y$ be any mean-$0$ random variable with nonzero variance, and let $X_k = kY$.

More generic: for any value $a$, and any non-negative value $b$, you can find a random variable with mean $a$ and variance $b$. So if $(a_n)$ is any sequence, and $(b_n)$ is any non-negative sequence, there is a sequence of random variables $(X_n)$ such that the sequence of means is $(a_n)$ and the sequence of variances is $(b_n)$.
